# Power supply or motherboard busted. How can I fix it quick?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power, case

A few days ago, my desktop PC just stopped turning on. Pressing the power switch elicits no response altogether.

This is the sum total of the troubleshooting steps I've done:

- Super-newbily switched power supply I/O switch off and on a number of times as recommended in the PSU manual.
- Also very newbily watched [a YouTube video about the power supply "paperclip test"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixcWCrYpw3Y) and verified that yes, I can jumpstart it with a paperclip.
- Exhausted my entire knowledge of electronics by unplugging all of my PC case's power switch/reset switch/case LED plugs from the motherboard and then tried to test if the case power switch is busted by closing the motherboard power switch circuit by touching a flat-head screwdriver to the two switch pins. Absolutely nothing happened. No PSU startup.

I do not own any testing tools like a multimeter or know much about electronics. I also value my time and would rather not spend hours diagnosing the problem if the balance of probabilities says "replace component X".

Should I just go ahead and buy a new PSU? Or are there some simple tests I can do using what I have around home that would give a clearer picture of whether it's the mobo or the power supply unit?

(*FWIW, it's a 350W [DiabloTek PSDA350 DA Series 350-Watt ATX Power Supply](http://www.amazon.ca/dp/B002RWJGCC) which I got for like $14.99 off of Amazon.ca one fine day. Always been a noisy bugger. Have a vague recollection of assuring myself it had enough juice to run my simple hardware when I bought it two years ago.*)

Comment: Can you use another PSU? Can you test the PSU on the other system?

Comment: If changing PSU won't solve the problem, then motherboard is broken.

Comment: @Tom, I'm afraid not easily. I only have the one PC, and only the one power supply in it...

Comment: In my opinion your PSU is broken 80 percents.

Comment: Ordered a new one last night - I want a new nice quiet one anyway. If that don't fix it, I'll have to get serious :)  By the way, @Tom, I assume this means inability to short-circuit the motherboard power switch doesn't necessarily indicate a motherboard problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the power supply. Replaced the two-year old 350W DiabloTek unit with a brand new fanless 460W Sea Sonic unit and it's humming away. And by humming, I mean humming barely audibly!